# How to properly configure a dconf schema from a gschema.xml file?

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell-extension, dconf, gsettings

Well, looking for manners of [manipulate dconf keys without a GUI](https://askubuntu.com/a/72093/689894) I realize that, only when correctly setup a `dconf` schema enables its key management through `GSettings` CLI.

I also observed that  ANY of [GNOME extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) I've choose to use (from a 22-item wide list) have done this properly (thus not providing `GSettings` manipulation). nevertheless, for example, it's just possible to query a dconf key type using `gsettings range` command, since [dconf](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf) in itself do not supply one operation for this purpose.

### Question

How should a `gschema.xml` file properly be *'installed'* in a `dconf` storage system?

Comment: if you have `gshema.xml` file you will typically compile it with the command `glib-compile-schemas`

Comment: Where should I store compiled file to ensure `gsettings` cli find it out?

Comment: you need to decide where to store between 2 choices.. as a root `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/yourgschema.xml` as a local user `$HOME/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/yourgschema.xml`

Comment: it is easier to answer if you show which gschema.xml are not showing...

Comment: you should not compile until you copy the `gschema.xml` file to any of the folder said above..

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the help, PRATAP. It's worked properly. Would you like to formalize an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your extension have `gschema.xml` file.. and after successful installation of the extension, if you dont find the gsetting keys mentioned in the gschema.xml file.. It indicates that the gschema.xml file is not compiled while the installation process..

In such case.. you need to manually compile the gschema.xml which is provided with the extension.

to compile the schemas.. first copy the `gschema.xml` provided by the extension, to any of the folder mentioned below..

```
$HOME/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

Where to copy in above two choices is self explanatory.. first one for local or per user based.. second one is global or admin based..

to compile the schemas.. run the below command from the any directory mentioned above.

```
glib-compile-schemas .
```

Example:

As a local user

```
cd $HOME/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas
glib-compile-schemas .
```

for global or as a Admin

```
cd /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
sudo glib-compile-schemas .
```

Note that, In a default installation `$HOME/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas` will not be available so you need to create the directories first with below command

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```

Similarly when you delete the extension or you want to remove the gsetting keys..

Delete the file `gschema.xml` and then run the `glib-compile-schemas` command.

Comment: Just one observation. Typically the GNOME extensions installed by the user are installed in $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions. Here you will find a folder for every extension. Inside every extension folder you'll find s folder called schemas where you find the gschema of that extension. This is the file to copy to $HOME/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas. This means that usually the gschemas are already available, you should simply put them in the correct folder and compile them.