# Why are my gnome extensions not listed in gsettings?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, dconf, gsettings

I want to automate my Ubuntu install and for that I also want to automatically install extensions and apply my settings.

Unfortunately, if I install my extensions via the browser, I can not get my settings from the gsettings tool.

If I view my extensions using the dconf editor like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178580/where-are-gnome-extensions-preferences-stored), I can see my settings, but in gsettings the schema just does not show up. The Ubuntu default extensions do show up though.

What can I do to read and write my extensions settings from the CLI?

Comment: can you share few extensions which you want to explore via cli?

Comment: @UnKNOWn for example: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1246650/739431 did you try this way to read the settings of the locally installed extension?

Comment: @UnKNOWn Thank you! That works flawlessly! Is there any reason why this is not done automatically?

Comment: that can be done if the extension is installed manually (not from gnome-extensions webpage) and if the extension author makes the compile commands in his install script.

Comment: @UnKNOWn Can you link me a source on how to install them manually? I had a hard time getting that to work too.

Comment: when you search for a extension in gnome-extensions site, you need to look for link of authors repository. If he as given instructions in his read me and if he really made the compile commands in his script then only it works. So its not 100% that we get compilation via manual installation.

Comment: https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/blob/master/Makefile it has compilation commands.

Comment: @UnKNOWn Ah okay I understand - I will stick to the manual process then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below commands one by one or in a script will show you the keys of the extension dash-to-panel

```
mkdir -p .local/share/glib-2.0/schemas
cp .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-panel.gschema.xml .local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
cd .local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
glib-compile-schemas .
cd
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-panel
```